# Wordpress - How to achieve this effect when admin adds image via post editor

Tags: image, wordpress

Im trying to figure out how to have this effect applied over all images that the admin adds to posts.  Tried CSS3, Pseudo Class, Jquery > Add Class and none seem to give me decent results that will adapt to image size.. I know I have seen this on other sites just dont know how to do it.

When admin adds an image or images to post I just want to have this effect applied to each image (see screenshot)

[image]

**[edit]**

Current CSS:

```
.overlay-top {
    background:url('images/top-right.png') no-repeat scroll top right transparent;
    height:85px;
    position:relative;
    top:55px;
    left:13%;
}

.overlay-bottom {
    background:url('images/bottom-left.png') no-repeat scroll top left transparent;
    height:85px;
    position:relative;
    bottom:70px;
    right:13%;
}

.img-overlay {
    width:auto !important;
}
```

Current JQuery:

```
$("#main a").has("img").addClass("img-overlay");
$("section.post_content a img").addClass("overlay-img");
$(".overlay-img").after("<div class='overlay-bottom'></div>");
$(".overlay-img").before("<div class='overlay-top'></div>");
```

before it was a psuedo class:

```
.img-overlay {
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
    width:90%;
    margin: 25px auto;
    position: relative;
}

.img-overlay:before {
    content: url('images/top-right.png');
    position: absolute;
    right: -33px;
    top: -19px;
}

.img-overlay:after {
    content: url('images/bottom-left.png');
    position: absolute;
    left: -31px;
    bottom: -23px;
}
```

How it is currently is the best I have been able to get it but it still isnt perfect and I have only tried with two different size images.

Comment: most recently I tried using JQuery to insert a class to the surrounding anchor tag then a div before and after the image with a class to get the image..  Before that it was a pseudo class with content: (my image) but with both I am having trouble because the anchor will not match the image size so the corners are way off the image..  Check it with large images here: itestwebpageshere.biz/gallery and with smaller images here: itestwebpageshere.biz/accommodations  .. and no I dont expect you to do it from scratch just correct what I have already, I'll update the above to show what I have tried

Comment: Have you tried the "web inspector" to see how does other website you mentioned are doing it?

Comment: I cant remember where I have seen this done before but know I have seen it..  Now I am having trouble finding a similar site

Comment: its like I can get it right on one page but when I goto the other page with the different size image (links above) then it isnt right and I believe it is because the surrounding anchor tag spans the width of the container instead of matching the width of the image.  Thats my biggest problem, if I could find a way to do this to the image itself or fix that anchor width

Answer (score 1):

Fixed it by removing most styling in .img-overlay selector and using the psuedo class and an inline-block on .img-overlay

Thanks